# PresentationFramework.Aero2 is not included in the ClickOnce deploy folder

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I'm trying to force a Win8 Desktop theme (PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll), but when I deploy the app with ClickOnce this assembly is not added to the deploy.

I've tried setting CopyToLocal=true - doesn't help. I attempted to "include" it in the ClickOnce installer, but it didn't even appear in the list.

What can be done?

Comment: It is included with the .NET Framework.  You don't deploy it yourself, just like you don't deploy, say, System.dll either.

Comment: @HansPassant that's a theme assembly. the OP should actually include that if he plans to have his WPF application maintain the `Aero2` (Windows 8) Theme in non-Windows 8 boxes.

Comment: @HighCore, Any idea why it's not being deployed? I even tried to manually copy the file to the deployed app folder, and it still didn't work.

Comment: @HansPassant Should this mean that the PresentationFramework.Aero and Aero2 assemblies can be found on all computers running Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me in a WPF application where I had a reference to an assembly that was not being included in the ClickOnce package, despite being set as `Include` in the Project deployment settings.

In my case the assembly was `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll`, but I guess your situation is the same.

I resolved this using a somewhat hacky solution:

Create a strong reference to the assembly by adding some code that references a class inside that assembly, for example:

```
public static class DummyClass
{
   public static Microsoft.Windows.Themes.BulletChrome DummyProperty {get;set;}
   //BulletChrome is a class defined in PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
}
```

I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution to this problem, but the above worked well for me.